# Role and architecture of Xorg (X server) and interaction with other software

Tags: xorg

I have been a Linux user for years now, but I still struggle to understand how X compares with the software used for display on Windows and Mac systems.

I know it is a client/server based software, but what is particularly puzzling for me is how it works with widget toolkits to provide a display and how these interact with each other.

I mean, take the Cocoa framework of Mac: You have GnuStep, which is an open source implementation of that framework, but (from what I can guess), it runs on X, right? Yet I suppose that Mac does not use X.

Are there any alternative options to Xorg on Linux? Can I run GnuStep, for example, with something else?

Are window managers and desktop environments written specifically to work with X or can they work with other display software?

Comment: OS X actually use X11, till 10.7, then switch to [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki) on 10.8 (Mountain Lion). A bit more info in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11.app) regarding this.

Comment: OK, that's interesting thanks. I tried Ctrl+Alt+F1/2/3 on a Mac notebook and because I couldn't switch into console mode, I just assumed they use something other than X.

Comment: `Ctrl+Alt+F1/2/3` is a linux thing :) OS X don't have that.

Comment: I guess it's more of a *nix thing, but I suppose you can configure your terminals such as to disable this behaviour. Which would make sense for a high-end commercial desktop like Mac. I mean imagine someone not familiar with the console pressing that combination by mistake; Apple would have endless support calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First check [Understanding linux desktop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55979/understanding-linux-desktop/55991#55991)

> I have been a Linux user for years now, but I still struggle to understand how X compares with the software used for display on Windows and Mac systems.
>
> I know it is a client/server based software, but what is particularly puzzling for me is how it works with widget toolkits to provide a display and how these interact with each other.
>
> I mean, take the Cocoa framework of Mac: You have GnuStep, which is an open source implementation of that framework, but (from what I can guess), it runs on X, right? Yet I suppose that Mac does not use X.

The toolkits (GTK, Qt...) generally do not interact among themselves - they are just libraries and as such (mostly) separated on a per process basis. They of course interact with the X server - by sending draw commands and reading inputs. However, some of them are not limited to a single backend (X11) - for example GTK, Qt and GNUstep have also MS Windows flavours.

The toolkits act as a unified API layer above the native drawing interface - in the case of X11 they translate request to draw a button into a series of simple objects (rectangles, shadings etc.; for example in recent GTK versions this is achieved through another abstraction layer provided by [Cairo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cairo_%28graphics%29)). On Windows or Mac they have the possibility to use the native API so that e.g. "GTK button" can be translated to "Windows Button", and for example on a framebuffer device it would be translated directly into the single pixels (probably again through a rastering engine like Cairo). For example Qt has about [15 various backends](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28framework%29#Platforms).

If you are talking about the desktop environments communicating with applications using different toolkits, that's a whole different story. These days, [D-Bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus) is usually used in an X session, which allows not only GUI applications to send and receive messages to/from other applications.

> Are there any alternative options to Xorg on Linux? Can I run GnuStep, for example, with something else?

One alternative (apart fom those mentioned by John Siu in his answer) might be [Wayland](http://wayland.freedesktop.org/). Yet there aren't many applications that would be able to use it **natively**.

> Are window managers and desktop environments written specifically to work with X or can they work with other display software?

Most of the time window managers only understand the X protocol and are supposed to be run under (or above, depending from which side one looks) the X server. Pretty much because there isn't anything better (even though there are things in X11 and it's implementations, that could be better).

Comment: Thanks, you have answered all my questions, and the links have pointed me in the right direction, and especially the information about D-bus is useful. My only query now is still how GTK manages to work on X11 and Windows, but I guess that is a question for another day...

Comment: The "toolkits" paragraph is what I originally planned to update in my answer. peterph did a good job here. +1

Comment: Check the updated answer on toolkit backends

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for alternate to X11 on Linux, there are a few base on [this post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=87281). However checking their wiki links, some of them seems no longer under development. Following are 2 that seems active

1. [DirectFB](http://www.directfb.org/)
2. [KDrive/TinyX](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jch/software/kdrive.html)

Personally I use/try directfb before. I was using Gentoo during that time and can specify window application compile with DirectFB library instead of X11 (or both? I forget.)

Comment: definition of gtk/gnustep/kde/cocoa are some how pretty blurry. Have to update those into answer later tonight.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had actually looked at that post prior to coming here; it just added to my confusion! I find the prospect of being able to use a different display program other than X11 a very enticing one, but it seems to me that you would have to rewrite a whole lot of software to make such a desktop useful.

Comment: Not exactly, for example DirectFB, you just need to set the compile option to use directfb library and many programs will just work. I remember replacing X11 completely for months with no issue.